# Adding element in two dimensional ArrayList

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, arraylist

I know that for arrays you can add an element in a two dimensional array this way:

```
 array[0][1] = 17; //just an example
```

How can I do the same thing with ArrayList?

Comment: @Joey: what do you doubt? Please see code in answer as it uses get(...).get(...). How does this disallow my comment above?

Comment: Whatever `get(1)` returns, assigning 17 to it won't add it to the List - and won't compile anyway, surely?

Comment: @Joey: Yep, you're right and i wasn't thinking. Must not be enough blood in my alcohol system right now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
myList.get(0).set(1, 17);
```

maybe?

This assumes a nested `ArrayList`, i.e.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> myList;
```

And to pick on your choice of words: This *assigns* a value to a specific place in the inner list, it doesn't *add* one. But so does your code example, as arrays are of a fixed size, so you have to create them in the right size and then assign values to the individual element slots.

If you actually want to *add* an element, then of course it's `.add(17)`, but that's not what your code did, so I went with the code above.

Comment: I'm so glad James Gosling scorned operator overloads.

Comment: ...where get(0) returns a List, of course. Also noting that 17 is autoboxed to `new Integer(17)`

Answer (score 3):

```
outerList.get(0).set(1, 17);
```

with outerList being a `List<List<Integer>>`.

Remember that 2-dimensional arrays don't exist. They're in fact arrays or arrays.

Comment: So if I had a 10x grid (2D array) if i wanted to add to the last item would it be `myList.get(9).set(9, <my Int>);` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
 ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
 data.add(new ArrayList<String>());
 data.get(0).add("String");
```

`ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` contains elements of type `ArrayList<String>`

Each element must be initialised

These elements contain elements of type `String`

To get back the `String` "String" in the 3-line example, you would use

```
String getValue = data.get(0).get(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> FLCP = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
FLCP.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
FLCP.get(0).add(new Integer(0));
```

Each element must be instantiated. Here the outer ArrayList has ArrayList element, and first you need to add an element to reference it using get method.

Some additional notes; after reading other answers and comments:

1> Each element must be instantiated; initialization is different from instantiation (refer to [flexJavaMysql](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1244085/flexjavamysql)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9550884/3155843))

2> In Java, 2-dimensional arrays do exist; C# doesn't have 2D arrays (refer to [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9550639/3155843))

Answer (score 1):

the way i found best and convinient for me was to declare ur 2d arrayList and then also a nornal mono-dimension array.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> 2darraylist = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> 1darraylist=new ArrayList<>();
```

then fill the '1D'array list and later add the 1D to the 2D array list.

```
1darraylist.add("string data");
2darraylist.add(idarraylist);
```

this will work as long as your problem is simply to add to elements to the list. if u want to add them to specific positions in the list, the the .get().set(); is what u wanna stick to.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] myList = {"a","b","c","d"};
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
data.add(new ArrayList<String>());
int outerIndex =0;
int innerIndex =0;
for (int i =0; i<list.length; i++) {
     data.get(outerIndex).add(innerIndex, list[i]);
     innerIndex++;
 }
System.out.println(data);
```

Simple for loop to add data to a multidimensional Array.
For every outer index you need to add

```
data.add(new ArrayList<String>());
```

then increment the outer index, and reset the inner index.
That would look something like this.

```
public static String[] myList = {"a", "b","-","c","d","-","e","f","-"};

public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> splitList(String[] list) {

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    data.add(new ArrayList<String>());
    int outerIndex =0;
    int innerIndex =0;
    for (int i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("will add: " + list[i]);
        if(!list[i].contains("-")) {
            System.out.println("outerIndex: " + outerIndex +" innerIndex: "+ innerIndex);
            data.get(outerIndex).add(innerIndex, list[i]);
            innerIndex++;
        } else {
            outerIndex++;    // will move to next outerIndex
            innerIndex = 0;  // reset or you will be out of bounds
            if (i != list.length-1) {
                data.add(new ArrayList<String>());  // create an new outer index until your list is empty
            }
        }
   }  
    return data;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(splitList(myList));
}
```